# API Server CORS whitelist for Cordova App

Tags: javascript, api, cordova, cors

I have an API server that has a CORS whitelist for API client domains, I want to call the same API server using a Cordova based Mobile App. What domain should I add to the whitelist for the Cordova client?
And I certainly do not want to allow all origins [so * is out of the question]
The API server is PHP running on NGINX

Comment: I am confused by this statement *I want to call the same API server using a Cordova based Mobile App.* The words you are using are techically correct, but your question makes little sense. I think you have a misunderstanding about how the [Cordova whitelist plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist) works.  FWIW: Cordova/Phonegap does NOT use CORS.

Comment: The question is not about the Cordova whitelist plugin, its about the server side whitelist.

Comment: I am being very clear on this. Cordova/Phonegap does NOT use CORS. CORS starts with client as part of the protocol. In the protocol, the server tells the client which domains to accept. Cordova/Phonegap ignore this. In addition, if you plan on using your App as a wrapper for your website, your app will be rejected by Google and Apple.

Comment: Again, I think you have a misunderstaning *about how Cordova/Phonegap work*. FWIW: @Sam has told you the same thing.

Comment: Worst thing is you have got good answers and comments, from people who know a lot about cordova and yet you tell them that they are wrong withouth trying what they told you. I'll tell you one more time. Cordova apps won't respect your server CORS configuration, they will connect anyway, so you don't have to configure anything on the server to allow cordova app connection. Try on a REAL device. If something doesn't work, the problem isn't the server CORS, is probably your cordova whitelist plugin configuration or the CSP meta tag (if you have one)

Comment: @jcesarmobile I understand all of you are trying to help and I appreciate that, but please understand that the server does not allow CORS to any domain that is not on its whitelist (be it Cordova App or not), its a feature for data security at the backend which I am not allowed to disable. So it is of no use to change Cordova settings as the server will not send any replies not matter what you change in Cordova. Anyways thanks for your time and help.

Comment: If you are using `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domains");` cordova app will access anyway. If you are doing some other check in code then it might now work

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the server restrictions to add another domain as you say, you could put a proxy on a URL somewhere, have the Cordova app talk to that and have the proxy make calls to your server which should then appear to come from a whitelisted domain.

Not ideal, but given the restrictions you describe it's a viable option.

You could use say Node/Express as a proxy, or configure nginx, use PHP if are familiar with that, there's a few options.

You might want to enable CORS on your proxy too to make sure you don't hit cross origin issues when testing the Cordova app in a browser.

Comment: Even if I do this, I would be allowing every domain the CORS access to server, just via a proxy instead of direct access. But I only want to allow a few domains CORS access to the server and also allow access to the Cordova app.

Comment: You can limit CORS domains through configuration then maybe also have some sort of token that the app can generate and the server validate for the Cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change anything at server side, while accessing from Cordova apps. Cross domain policy will not apply as the request is over `file://` and not `http`. However, in your Cordova config.xml, you will need to add domain that you are accessing to a whitelist like this -

```
<access origin="http://example.com" />
```

You can read more about it here - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html

Comment: The config.xml already has: <access origin="*" />       But the problem is there is a whitelist implemented at the server.

Comment: Are you testing this from a browser?

Comment: You can also disable CORS altogether on your server. It shouldn't make an effect.

Comment: Testing from browser as well as emulators. Please read my question carefully, I cannot disable CORS or allow all.

Comment: If you are testing from browser (and possibly emulators), cross origin request will not go through due to same origin policy. Try once by installing the app on phone.

Comment: I think you are not getting the point here, the server does not allow CORS but except from those domains that exist in its whitelist. So I want to figure out how to configure it to allow CORS from whitelist and the Cordova App as well.

Comment: If server is restricting and you can't change, then you can't do much with that, can you? That is the whole point of maintaining a whitelist or implementing CORS.

Comment: I can change the server restrictions, for eg. I can add another domain if I want to for a browser client, but I don't know what to add to allow the Cordova App.